# Printing random characters when reading file

Tags: c, file, fread

I have a config.txt file that looks like this:

```
2
2
[3, 8]
[4, 2]-[12, 7]
[1, 10]-[12, 1]
```

And I am trying to read its content to process later. However, when I was trying my program and printing the file content it ouputs more characters than are in the file, even when I terminate the string myself. It's like the length of the file is overestimated by the program. This is the output of the printf:

```
2
2
[3, 8]
[4, 2]-[12, 7]
[1, 10]-[12, 1]df
```

Obviously the two characters *df* should not be there. What am I doing wrong. I googled around but I can't find a clear answer. This is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readFile(const char *fileName, char *text);

void readFile(const char *fileName, char *text)
{
    FILE *f;
    long length;

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (f);
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    text = malloc(length + 1);
    if(text)
    {
        fread (text, 1, length, f);
    }
    fclose (f);
    text[length] = '\0';

    printf(text);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *fileText;
    readFile("config.txt", fileText);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, that did it. Do you know why it gave this weird behavior when I used just "r"?

Comment: That worked too, however, calloc initializes the values of the text array to 0. If you try to print a char that is intialized to 0, nothing is printed. But this still means the size of the array is too big, only the excess elements don't get printed. Wouldn't it still be better to to use "rb" for reading the file even though your solution does work?

Comment: wait, '\0' and 0 both terminate a string then?

Comment: @Anteino,  Both `'\0'` and `0` are integers with the value zero and can be used interchangeably. They are different representations of the same number.

Comment: Now the fileText variable seems to be empty outside of the readFile function. But how can that be? I am passing it by reference. This pointer stuff always gets me so confused...

Comment: I tried the latter option in different ways for an hour but I am unable to figure it out. Can you write a small code example on how to pass arrays by reference properly? I am not asking you to write my code for me but I just can't see it.

Comment: I believe I figured it out, if you pass fileText by double reference, to index it, you need to wrap the variable in parentheses and then do the indexing. Like this: **(*text)[*filelen] = 0**.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: ` = fopen(fileName, "r");
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (f);
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);`  These statements, like most functions in the C library, return an indicator of when an error occurs.   The code should always be checking for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) already suggested, changing "r" to "rb" in the fopen statement fixed the problem.